# Django pull list of all users, but shows list of multiple users with only current users credentials

Tags: python, django

In Django, I am trying to get a list of all users. I use the following query:

```
users = User.objects.all().order_by('id')
```

I am able to get a list of all the users, but it outputs a list of all users, but only showing the current users credentials? If I have 20 users, it will show 20 users but only the information for the currently logged in user. For example, I want to see a table like:

```
User | Email
------------
User1 | user1@test.com
User2 | user2@test.com
User3 | user3@test.com
```

But if the current user that is logged in is User1, It shows:

```
User | Email
------------
User1 | user1@test.com
User1 | user1@test.com
User1 | user1@test.com
```

Or if User2 is logged in, it shows:

```
User | Email
------------
User2 | user2@test.com
User2 | user2@test.com
User2 | user2@test.com
```

Here is my **view.py**:

```
def portal_users(request):
   users = User.objects.all().order_by('id')
   return render(request, 'portal/users.html', {"users": users})
```

**templates**

```
{% for users in users %}
       <tr>
        <td>{{user.username}}</td>
        <td>{{user.email}}</td>
       </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your template to the following:

```
{% for user in users %}
<tr>
    <td>{{user.username}}</td>
    <td>{{user.email}}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

You are referencing `users` as opposed to `user`.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the `user` variable inside a template references the current user,  that's why you are printing the current user instead of an item in the `users` list. Now you may say "even if that is happening the for loop should overwrite the `user` variable inside the loop" and you are right!, but in this case, your for loop is `{% for users in users %}`, notice that you are using `users` for the variable and the iterable, so your loop should be `{% for user in users %}`.